# Does duplex patch fiber optic cable (LC-LC) need termination box/splicing?

Tags: networking, cable, fiber

The duplex fiber optic cable (LC-LC) I am talking about looks like this
[image]

I am trying to run an outdoor cable about 120m and was informed that I need to have splicing and a termination box. But based on this picture it seems I can just have this kind of connector which is 120m long and plug into a SFP module on both end?

Comment: Not an expert, but while they certainly make _short_ pre-terminated patch cords for indoor use (up to a few dozen meters), I suspect that a product for 120m outdoor use might look completely different from this (much stronger shielding, etc.) and not necessarily pre-terminated. [For example](https://www.fs.com/c/indoor-outdoor-multifiber-cables-1155)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could - provided you can find one long enough and appropriate for outdoor usage. The outdoor cables must sustain weather conditions, especially UV radiation coming from the Sun - they are **usually** black, as the jacket colors **usually** are meaningful (e.g. the patchcord from your photo is apparently some multimode).

Comment: I see it starts to make sense now. If you don't mind can you explain this as well... Why is splicing required when I can just put the fiber glass into the connector? I see internet guy came to my home with a cutter and do it that way.

Comment: There are physical fast-connectors that can be clamped on the fiber and if properly assembled they are good enough. So in general - splicer is not required. But the experience is - both with splicing and fast-connectors. But what's preferable - depends, mostly on costs, but also on type of cable. If you need 1J or 2J cable, a few connectors would do the job, but if you build some 48J one you want the termination box and patch panels to save space and keep some order.

Comment: @Zanko: As I understand it, it simply depends on how much signal loss you can tolerate. There are various purely mechanical methods, they just vary in reliability (and none of them are quite as good as fusion splicing). It also varies based on how well you cut the fiber, how well you clean the ends...